# PHP работа с добавлением и обработкой фото для сайта

Tags: php, изображения, png, gif, jpeg

Доброго времени.
Никому не встречалось готовое решение на PHP для работы с загрузкой и обработкой фото?
Необходимо при добавлении фото на сайт (jpeg, png, gif), любого размера, вставлять его в белый квадрат с определенными размерами, например 600*600px (а исходное фото может быть 700*300px), уменьшить добавляемое фото до ширины или высоты необходимое для вставки в границы и врисовывание его в центр этого белого квадрата.
Ну сохранение и аплоад на готового фото хост, без или с созданием thumb

Comment: verot.net только сейчас у меня не грузится он, но очень хороший и удобный класс.

Comment: Спасибо. Разберу